# C++ OpenMP Tasks - passing by reference issue

Tags: c++, reference, io, parallel-processing, openmp

I am currently working on a system in which I reading in a file of over ~200 million records (lines), so I am buffering the records and using OpenMP tasks to manage each batch while continuing to process input. Each record in the buffer takes roughly 60μ to process in `work_on_data`, and will generate a string result. To avoid critical regions, I create a vector for results, and pass record placeholders (that I insert into this vector) by address to the `work_on_data` function :

```
int i = 0;
string buffer[MAX_SIZE];
vector<string> task_results;

#pragma omp parallel shared(map_a, task_results), num_threads(X) 
#pragma omp single
{
    while (getline(fin, line) && !fin.eof())
    {
        buffer[i] = line;
        if (++i == MAX_SIZE)
        {
            string result = "";
            task_results.push_back(result);
#pragma omp task firstprivate(buffer)
            work_on_data(buffer, map_a, result);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}

// eventually merge records in task_results
```

At the end of `work_on_data`, each `result` passed in will not be an empty string (as initialized). **However, when merging results, each result is still an empty string.** I may be doing something stupid here regarding scoping/addressing, but I don't see what the problem is. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing something into a vector causes a copy of it to be constructed inside the vector. So your `work_on_data` function doesn't get a reference to the string inside the vector, but to the string inside the if block. To fix this you could rewrite your code to give it access to the last element after the push_back, like so:

```
if (++i == MAX_SIZE)
{
    task_results.push_back("");
#pragma omp task firstprivate(buffer)
    work_on_data(buffer, map_a, task_results.back());
    i = 0;
}
```

**Edit**:

I had forgotten about iterator invalidation on vector reallocation, and additionally the call to `back()` leads to race conditions. With (smart) pointers (as the comments are suggesting) and a dedicated counter this works for me with no segfault:

```
vector<shared_ptr<string>> task_results;

int ctr = 0
...
if (++i == MAX_SIZE) {
    task_results.push_back(make_shared<string>());
#pragma omp task firstprivate(buffer, ctr) 
    work_on_data(buffer, map_a, *task_results.back[ctr]);
    i = 0;
    ++ctr;

}
```

I think the `back()` version segfaults because that function is being called by many different threads at the same time and if the main thread manages to `push_back` somewhere in between as well, threads would be working on the same data.

Comment: I am assuming this wouldn't cause a problem if the `push_back` was called again during a task? Thanks! I'll give it a go.

Comment: Seg faults. I believe this could be down to `push_back` being dangerous given `std::vector` isn't thread safe. Not quite sure how to get around this given the nature of tasks!

Comment: @PidgeyBAWK Try using a `vector<string*>`, with `string *result = new string()` and `push_back(result)`, or equivalent with a C++ pointer class. This way the string will be passed correctly.

Comment: @ElderBug Thanks for your comment, that makes sense and I will give it a go - time to find the right C++ smart point. Am I right in thinking if `push_back` causes the vector to resize and reallocate (I can't rely on reserve in advance), this memory address will remain valid?

Comment: @PidgeyBAWK Yes it will. The pointer itself in the vector will be relocated, but your task have a copy of that pointer, which will still point to the correct string (vector only manage the memory it allocated itself).